# Reset parent container (that is, set somehow "rendered" flag to false)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a component (let it be Ext.panel.Panel, does not really matters), and want to change dynamically its parent container - the one we are setting via renderTo.

As far as I understand after inspecting code - there is a `rendered` flag and it is checked each time  one is trying to call `render` method. But I can see the place where we can reset parent container.

I can keep skimming over code, but it would be very nice if somebody who knows something about this topic would explain me. So, **can we reset dynamically parent container**?

Or, in case we want to look at the problem from another side - **is it possible to dynamically add items to layout**?

To be less abstract, let me provide you an example when we actually might need this. Imagine two panels with some child windows (draggable). It would be nice sometimes to have an opportunity to drag child windows from one panel to another.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I get it. It's rather simple.
All i need it to use parent containers `add` method.